# Scikit documentation -- missing details or am I not looking in the right place?

Tags: scikit-learn

What is the function `K` in the following link.  I want to really understand how this algorithm works.  Please advise:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mean-shift

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's the [rbf kernel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) since the first parameter in [MeanShift](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn.cluster.MeanShift) is the bandwidth of the kernel.

EDIT: `K` is a actually a flat (uniform) kernel. A good diagram with the different kernel types is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Some_of_the_kernels_mentioned_above_in_a_common_coordinate_system

Comment: That could be the case, but the kernel is said to be flat in the docs. Does that change anything?

Comment: You're right, they are using a flat (uniform) kernel. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Some_of_the_kernels_mentioned_above_in_a_common_coordinate_system